# proposeedit venue method of foursquare api is responding nothing

Tags: api, ios5, foursquare

I am trying to edit a venue using https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/proposeedit  of the Foursquare API, but in the response, I am always getting a blank dictionary and changes are not done successfully.
and my response is

```
meta = {code = 200; }; notifications = ( {item ={unreadCount = 0;}; type = notificationTray;        });response ={};
```

Comment: Are you providing any credentials while accessing the foursquare api?

Comment: meta =     {
        code = 200;
    };
    notifications =     (
                {
            item =             {
                unreadCount = 0;
            };
            type = notificationTray;
        }
    );
    response =     {
    };
 this is my response and i also providing access token

Answer (score 0):

When I have tried to access the given URL the response is 
**{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}**

so if you can see errorDetails , it is giving reason in message detail that access credentials are required so if you can provide, than response may not be empty.
Currently response is empty due to ERROR in response

Comment: meta =     {
        code = 200;
    };
    notifications =     (
                {
            item =             {
                unreadCount = 0;
            };
            type = notificationTray;
        }
    );
    response =     {
    };

Comment: Hi zaffargachal can you please reply for the response  which added with question.